# Generating a rectangle in windows store app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to generate a rectangle dynamicaly when a button is pressed in a windows store app
I've tried

Rect r = new Rect();

myGrid.Children.Add(r);

but it gives me an error
"The best overloaded method match for 'name' has some invalid arguments"

what's the problem?

Comment: Visual Studio will tell you *where* the error is - it doesn't seem like the code you posted will give that error (there's no `name` anywhere in it). Try looking at the error and seeing where the actual error is. I imagine it's not in those two lines.

Comment: the actual msg is  "The best overloaded method match for 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UIElementCollection.Add(Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: VS should give you a bit more detail about the error, like which parameters aren't matching, can you provide the entire details...

Comment: the parametre "r" isn"t matching

Comment: by the way i've tried adding other UI elements using this method and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
myGrid.Children.Add(r);
```

Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thanks I've just found what's missing it's "using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;"

Answer (score 0):

`Rect` is a simple struct. You want [`Rectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.rectangle.aspx)

Comment: there's no Rectangle how can I add it?

Comment: If you click the link, you will see the namespace to add to your `using` statements